# Put a text on fullscreen video (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I want to put text on fullscreen video at HTML.

I could make it non fullscreen but it is not working on fullscreen.

Is there any way to do it?

I use `position:absoulute` for text and `position:relative/fixed/none` for video.

Also I don't know if it works but I called `.requestFullscreen();` function for browser unhappily I cannot resize video.

If `.requestFullscreen();` is works. I need to resize video.

width and height of video tags is changing but video is not changing.

Comment: Can we have your code in fiddle.

Comment: Please post a demo in jsFiddle.net.  I've had troubles as you have described, but it's better if I can see what you've already done so I don't have to "reinvent the wheel"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed responsively with Youtube and vimeo with iframes, and with Viddler and Blip.tv with object embed. There is an article that explains it [here](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) and code is available on [github](https://github.com/chriscoyier/Fluid-Width-Video)

Sample code for Youtube (using jquery):

```
// Find all YouTube videos
var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='//www.youtube.com']"),

    // The element that is fluid width
    $fluidEl = $("body");

// Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
$allVideos.each(function() {

  $(this)
    .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

    // and remove the hard coded width/height
    .removeAttr('height')
    .removeAttr('width');

});

// When the window is resized
$(window).resize(function() {

  var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

  // Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
  $allVideos.each(function() {

    var $el = $(this);
    $el
      .width(newWidth)
      .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

  });

// Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem before but it's pretty simple code in the end (it still took me ages to figure out and get the right balance) https://jsfiddle.net/tonytansley/xwuuttdt/

Just a little absolute positioning and using percentages as your widths heights and paddings.

```
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="home-top-video">
            <video autoplay loop width="100%">
                <source src="http://view.vzaar.com/2710053.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
                <source src="http://view.vzaar.com/2710053.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
                <source src="http://view.vzaar.com/2710053.webm" type="video/webm"/>
            Your browser does not support the video tag. We suggest you upgrade your browser.
            </video>
            <div id="home-text">
                    <h1>text</h1>
                    <h3>subtext</h3>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css

```
#outer{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:10000px;
    min-height:100%;
}
#home-top-video{
    left:0%;
    top:0%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
#home-text{
    left:0%;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    color:white
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this in a couple different ways. I believe the easiest would be to create a div that's 100% width, embed the video responsively inside the div, and then absolutely position the text in the center of the div.